# Sublime Text 3 - g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: sublime-text-3, mingw

I am trying to set up Sublime Text 3 so I am able to build and run c++ files. I have installed MinGW, and added C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe to my system path, but I am still receiving this error after restarted Sublime Text 3. Here is the full error message

> 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
>   [shell_cmd: g++ "C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Scripts\test.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Scripts/test"]
>   [dir: C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Scripts]
>   [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin;C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe]

Comment: `PATH` contains _directories_, not executable file names.

Comment: thank you. just to clarify, i should have C:\MinGW\bin in my path rather than the executable?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know MinGW, so I don't know if it will use the Windows `PATH`, or whether it needs the `g++` directory in `PATH` in the MinGW environment.

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to do the trick.